# Have on + whether or not

Tags: grammaticality

[image]

Q: Is this sentence correct? (see image).

If so, how? I know that **have on [something]** would make sense, but **have on whether ... or not**? This, I'm not sure. Please someone explain this to me.

Comment: _Whether_ is the _wh_-word used for embedding yes/no questions. _Is he coming tonight?_ can be used as a subject or object clause: _Whether he's coming tonight is the big question_, or _I don't know whether he's coming tonight._ The "or not" can go at the end or the beginning; it's free, because there are only two answers to a yes/no question -- _whether_ covers yes, and _or not_ covers no -- if you want to mention it. If you do, it can go either place.

Comment: As for _have on_, it is not involved in this sentence. Subject _impact_, verb phrase _will have on_ + _whether_ clause as object.

Answer (score 1):

*whether* is a conjunction that links two mutually exclusive possibilities.

> [Oxford Learners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/weather)
> *whether*
> used to express a doubt or choice between two possibilities
> *He seemed undecided whether to go or stay
>
> It remains to be seen whether or not this idea can be put into practice
>
> I'll see whether she's at home (= or not at home)*

The linking creates a noun phrase of two possibilities. Which possibility becomes true depends on some external factor.

In the first two examples the possibilities are explicit. The determining factor is the way he decides (first example) or future developments (second example).

In the third example the second possibility is not stated but is implied; the result will be determined by a visit to the home.

In your example, *whether names are written permanently or not* is a noun phrase whose final meaning will only be determined by the effect of the *program*.

Either the names will be permanently written, or they will not. The program will determine which of these possibilities is realised.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatical but decidedly awkward. It would be much better without "or not".

When a *whether* clause is used adverbially, it requires an *or*, but when a *whether* clause is used as a noun phrase, for example as the object of the preposition *on*, "or not" is generally superfluous.

In this particular paragraph, the whether clause acts as a question within a question, and "or not" distracts the reader from the intended overall meaning.